# NetBoot Server Alternatives for macOS 10.14 Mojave?

Tags: network, osx-server, netboot

Apple has removed, among many other things, DHCP serving and `NetBoot` Serving from their 'server' app in conjunction with the new OS. This won't affect 99.5% of people but I'm in the minority. I fix Macs for a living and have been using `Netbooting` for 10 years as my faster, better version of booting a customers Mac off a USB utility disk. I use `NetInstall` images too for installing the OS but I primarily use Diskless `NetBoot` images to diagnose and repair disk problems. I run this on my laptop, plug into someone's network, and BAM. Or what is more often the case, on wifi-only networks, I just plug in directly mac to mac and use DHCP service also running on my laptop.

Well both services are gone. DHCP is easy enough to replace I'm sure, but `NetBoot` serving doesn't seem as straight forward. I did some googling but only found solutions that support `NetInstall`, and not `diskless-NetBoot` images. I need the latter more than anything.

I know Apple may be working towards killing NetBooting entirely, but it's not dead yet. And I tend to work on older computers more than new, so I still need `NetBoot` for years to come. I am currently playing around with running 10.11 in a virtual machine on my laptop. But that's not an ideal solution, i'd rather run a direct, native server.

`BSDPy` does not support diskless netbooting, so that option won't work.
I was eyeing `DeployStudio` but its not clear if that app IS it's own `NetBoot` server, or if it just works with Apple's `NetBoot` server?

Answer (score 1):

What about a netSUS server?

https://github.com/jamf/NetSUS

Just a thought, but I've run one and it works great

Comment: Do you know if this software supports Diskless NetBoot images?

Comment: Have you tried doing a dual install?

https://macpaw.com/how-to/dual-boot-two-macos
https://web.archive.org/web/20230325201842/https://macpaw.com/how-to/dual-boot-two-macos